# extracting and creating ipk files

Tags: package

ipk packages are the intallation packages used by opkg.

I'm trying to extract the contents of one of them and also create my own ipk.

I've read that I should be able to untar them but that is not true.

I've tried:

```shell
tar -zxvf mypack.ipk
```

and I get:

`zip: stdin: not in gzip format`

I've also tried:

```sh
tar -xvf mypack.ipk
```

and I get:

`tar: This does not look like a tar archive`

I've found that most of the information on the internet regarding ipk's are inaccurate.

My ipk was generated by bitbake. I'm having a hard time with bitbake and want to avoid using it.

Any ideas on how to extract and how to create ipk files? A simple template with a single package would be useful to have.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can extract the main package with the `ar x` command, then extract the control.tar.gz with the `tar -zxf` command.

Answer (score 24):

I have tested "ar x package-name.ipk" command but it didn't help

I found bellow command which worked perfectly

`tar zxpvf package-name.ipk`

This extracts three files:

debian-binary

data.tar.gz

control.tar.gz

use the same command to open data.tar.gz and control.tar.gz files

for more information refer to 
https://cognito.me.uk/computers/manual-extractioninstallation-of-ipk-packages-on-gargoyleopenwrt/

Answer (score 20):

You need to create a `control` file, and then do some archiving using `tar` and `ar`. In my case, I was distributing just python scripts, so there was no architecture dependency.  You should check the `control` and `Makefile` into version control, and delete all the other intermediate files.

Here are the contents of `control`

```
Package: my-thing-python
Version: 1.0
Description: python scripts for MyCompany
Section: extras
Priority: optional
Maintainer: John 
License: CLOSED
Architecture: all
OE: my-thing-python
Homepage: unknown
Depends: python python-distutils python-pyserial python-curses python-mmap python-ctypes
Source:  N/A
```

Here is my `Makefile` which sits in the same directory as all my python scripts.

```
all: my-thing-python.ipk


my-thing-python.ipk:
        rm -rf ipk
        mkdir -p ipk/opt/my-thing-python
        cp *.py ipk/opt/my-thing-python
        tar czvf control.tar.gz control
        cd ipk; tar czvf ../data.tar.gz .; cd ..
        echo 2.0 > debian-binary
        ar r my-thing-python.ipk control.tar.gz data.tar.gz  debian-binary

clean: FORCE
        rm -rf ipk
        rm -f control.tar.gz
        rm -f data.tar.gz
        rm -f my-thing-python.ipk

FORCE:
```

Comment: @MarkLakata, After installing the package, it gives an error as `Collected errors:
 * pkg_init_from_file: Malformed package file my-thing-python.ipk.`. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36331535/2706918)

Comment: What does `OE:` stand for?

Comment: @kmort - good question about `OE:`. I showed it in the example as a result of reverse engineering. I don't know what it means. It's possible that it is not standard.

Answer (score 5):

Extracting with these commands:

1. Extract the file by running the command:

   ```
     ar -xv   <.ipk file>
   ```
2. Extract the control.tar.gz file by running the command:

   ```
     tar -zxvf control.tar.gz
   ```
3. data.tar.gz : untar by running the command:

   ```
        tar –zxvf data.tar.gz
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of files in an ipk, you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f
do
   tar -x -z -f $f ./data.tar.gz -O | tar tvzf -
done
```

-O is extract to standard output.
ipk files used to be AR (like DPKG), but are now tgz.
I feel that some dpkg utility ought to cope with ipkg files, but I haven't found the right one.