# Can buildroot rootfs install angstrom package using opkg?

Tags: linux, beagleboard, buildroot, rootfs

I’m using beagleboard-xm,and created rootfs with buildroot,adding [opkg package](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/?id=20d4b4148f3bd2697093ab8adef4f642c358581d). Now, I want add some package in angstrom, so I add opkg update source in /etc/opkg/base-feed.conf…

`src/gz base http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/unstable/ipk/glibc/armv7a/base/`

“opkg update” command reports many error message “has no valid architecture, ignoring.”

`[root@beagleboard-xm ~]# opkg-cl update
Downloading http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/unstable/ipk/glibc/armv7a/base//Packages.gz.
Collected errors:
 * pkg_hash_add_from_file: Package a52dec-doc version 0.7.4-r4.7 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
 * pkg_hash_add_from_file: Package a52dec version 0.7.4-r4.7 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
 * pkg_hash_add_from_file: Package abiword-dev version 2.8.6-r7.17 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
 * pkg_hash_add_from_file: Package abiword-doc version 2.8.6-r7.17 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
 * pkg_hash_add_from_file: Package abiword-meta version 2.8.6-r7.17 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
 * pkg_hash_add_from_file: Package abiword-plugin-applix version 2.8.6-r7.17 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
......`

Then I manually download the package,and extract it as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369127/extracting-and-creating-ipk-files),and copy to beagleboard-xm. When running,it report”No such file or directory”

`[root@beagleboard-xm ~]# fbi
-bash: /usr/bin/fbi: No such file or directory`

But in [this link](http://eagerbeagler.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/bring-your-beagle-up-to-date/),opkg can install own build ipk package. Is there some difference in the ipk control file? 
Why the program running normally in angstrom,but can’t running in buildroot system?

---

I get it.
When i adding "/etc/opkg/arch.conf",it seems ok.

Answer (score 3):

By mixing binaries from one distribution (Angstrom) with another (Buildroot), you're likely to run into numerous ABI compatibility issues. What you're trying to do doesn't make much sense: if you want to use Angstrom packages, use Angstrom, not Buildroot.